# Real/imaginary part of sympy complex matrix

Tags: matrix, complex-numbers, sympy

Here is my problem.

I'm using sympy and a complex matrix P (all elements of P are complex valued).
I wanna extract the real/imaginary part of the first row.

So, I use the following sequence:

```
import sympy as sp

P = sp.Matrix([ [a+sp.I*b,c-sp.I*d], [c-sp.I*d,a+sp.I*b] ])
Row = P.row(0)
Row.as_mutable()
Re_row = sp.re(Row)
Im_row = sp.im(Row)
```

But the code returns me the following error:

"AttributeError: ImmutableMatrix has no attribute as_coefficient."

The error occurs during the operation sp.re(Row) and sp.im(Row)...
Sympy tells me that Row is an Immutable matrix but I specify that I want a mutable one...

So I'm in a dead end, and I don't have the solution...

Could someone plz help me ?
thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Most SymPy functions won't work if you just pass a Matrix to them directly. You need to use the methods of the Matrix, or if there is not such method (as is the case here), use `applyfunc`

```
In [34]: Row.applyfunc(re)
Out[34]: [re(a) - im(b)  re(c) + im(d)]

In [35]: Row.applyfunc(im)
Out[35]: [re(b) + im(a)  -re(d) + im(c)]
```

(I've defined `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` as just ordinary symbols here, if you set them as real the answer will come out much simpler).